# Using polymer-dart with html generated server-side by Django

Tags: django, dart, polymer

The dart-polymer transformer assumes that your html are static assets. But I want my html to be dynamically generated server-side. The reason for this is that I want to build a multi-page web-app (or perhaps I should call it a multi-app web-site), and use server-side templating to keep the page structure between pages.

Is there a way to use dart-polymer without using the "compiled" html produced by the polymer transformer? Ideally I want to serve a page like this from the server:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    <script type="application/dart"
            src="packages/web_components/webcomponents.dart"></script>

    <title>Films</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <link rel="import" href="player/film_player.html"/>
    <link rel="import" href="filmlist/film_list.html"/>
</head>
<body>
    <film-player id="player"></film-player>

    <film-list href="/api/movies"></film-list>

    <script type="application/dart" src="main.dart"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know it is not supported having `dart.js` at the top, but it would be nice if `dart.js` did as `webcompontents.dart.js` need to run before the html import tags. At least I guess it does.

I really would like to avoid all the javascript and css inlining done by polymer transformer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymer.dart doesn't support that scenario.
I'm not sure I understand your multi-page attempt. Dart is much better used for single-page application where you dynamically change what is shown at the current page. If you navigate to other pages a whole new Dart application is loaded and you don't have access to variables of the previous page and it is slow because Dart has some overhead and that only pays off if you stick to the one page.

A typical Dart application is built so that the client is basically an entire application that communicates with one or more servers but only sends and receives data but not application logic or views (except for very specific use cases).

Dart supports lazy loading to not load the entire application at once but not yet for Polymer.

Comment: I think Dart as a language should avoid making assumptions on what kind of app you make. Single-page apps is a good fit for applications, but not for web sites. And I do care about search friendliness and semantic mark-up. What I want to create is more like a web-site with multiple small applications. It would be awesome if the dart overhead could be compiled into it's own js file, so that the overhead did not need to be in every js file compiled from dart code.

Comment: Dart is no good fit for web sites. Its main target are web applications. Maybe dev_compiler https://github.com/dart-lang/dev_compiler provides that eventually.

Comment: That is too bad, because I find the Dart language quite appealing.

Comment: Yeah it is,  but not every scenario is fully supported yet.